# Display of downloaded files with the Dock icon

Tags: finder, dock

Using a Mac, with the downloads folder placed on the Dock, the downloaded files were displayed in a linear curved stack (when clicked) with the last downloaded files on the bottom and earlier downloads atop of it. This was convenient for managing recent downloads. Now, for some mysterious reason, clicking the downloads icon on my Dock yields a n by m display of icons within which I can't identify the latest downloads.

How to get it back to the way it was before?

Answer (score 2):

The view mode of your downloads folder on the dock probably changed. Secondary-click (right-click / ctrl-click) the icon, then under the "Display contents as" section, click "Fan". Also, on top of the list, be sure that "Date added" is checked under "Sort by".